# UIWebView keyboard with modal view dismissal, display issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, modalviewcontroller

i have a UIWebView on a modal view. The problem is that when the keyboard comes up for the UIWebView and I then dismiss the modal view, the underlying UINavigationController which has a UITableView on a UIScrollView will not display properly. it looks like the entire view(now sure if it's the table view or the scroll view) is shifted down to the middle of the screen. this only occurs if the web view keyboard comes up. it does not happen any other time. i can dismiss the modal view and it will display the underlying view fine, provided the web view keyboard is never initiated.

once that underlying view is up all i have to do is tap the screen and it goes back to where it should be.

i've tried to get the view to refresh with a

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

and that didn't do anything for it.

then i tried this to reset them back to their starting positions

```
myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 0, 0, 0);
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and that didn't work.

is there another way to get the underlying view to redraw? both the tableview and the scollview have paging enabled. there are other modal views that do not cause any issues when dismissing to this same view controller. i'm not hiding any navigation bars or anything like that.

thanks guys, any help is greatly appreciated!
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I know for certain why your table moves, but it's odd to put a table in a scroll view, since UITableView **is** a scroll view. I'd suggest ditching the scroll view if possible. Also, if you haven't already tried it, make sure that you dismiss the keyboard before you dismiss the modal view. You can do that by having the web view -resignFirstResponder.

Comment: that is an excellent point. i'm still knew to this and that part of the program was put in place very early in my learning. i'm going to re-examine that.

Comment: i just went in and removed the scrollview and the problem went away. i have no idea what the problem was with the scrollview, but seeing as how i don't even need it and it was a leftover from pour programing, i'll just go with it. thanks!